# Using PreviousControl property with nested subforms and controls

Tags: vba, ms-access, nested

I am creating a custom floating number pad so that tablet users can more easily tap numerical data into a form.  I'm using toggle buttons (the idea is to eventually highlight them briefly).  The following code for the number pad works on my main form's controls.  When I click on the 1 button, then a 1 is put into the active control of the main form

```vb
Private Sub Form_Activate()
  FocusForm = Application.Screen.PreviousControl.Parent.Name
  FocusControl = Application.Screen.PreviousControl.Name
End Sub

Private Sub Toggle1_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
'Add a 1 to the currently selected control
  Dim refControl As Control
  If FocusForm = "" Then End
  Set refControl = Forms(FocusForm).Controls(FocusControl)

  If (IsNull(refControl)) Then
    refControl = "1"
  Else
    refControl.Text = refControl.Text & "1"
  End If
  refControl.SetFocus
End Sub
```

However, if I navigate into the subform then the Screen.PreviousControl properties return the main form's name and the subform's name, but I can't then seem to be able to refer to the subform control's name as well.  Bascially I'm looking for a line that does the following

```
FocusForm = Application.Screen.PreviousControl.Parent.Name
FocusSubform = Application.Screen.PreviousControl.Name
FocusSubformControl = ?????
```

Similarly, my subform has its own nested subform and I would like to do the same with this

```
FocusForm = Application.Screen.PreviousControl.Parent.Name
FocusSubform = Application.Screen.PreviousControl.Name
FocusSubform2 = ?????
FocusSubform2Control = ?????
```

The in-built floating number pad on the tablets is very fiddly to use, hence my coding of this custom one, however if someone knows where I might find code for a customisable number pad that writes directly into whatever window is active, this would similarly be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If called from a subform,`Screen.PreviousControl`returns the name of the mainforms subfom-**control** (as mainform needs to be active to get the subform control (nested in mainform) active), not the subform (but they can have same name, just change controls name and you won't get subforms name returned, but subforms control name!).

Now how to get previous control of the subform? By its`.ActiveControl`property, as form was active before, its active control must be the previous control. (if you want to get previous control, when you stay on the same subform, you need to store it in a module variable)

As there may be multiple subforms inside of subforms, we just loop while the control is a subform and set it to the next subform`.ActiveControl`till finished.

Why bother with names, if you can use references? This enables using multiple instances of a form.
Just store the reference to the control in Form_Activate and use it in`MouseUp`:

```vb
'On top of forms code module
Option Explicit

Private PreviousFormControl As Access.Control

Private Sub Form_Activate()
  On Error Resume Next ' ignore error if no previous control availible
  Set PreviousFormControl = Application.Screen.PreviousControl ' this stores the reference not the name!
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      'Handle error here, e.g. disable controls, show msg, ...
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0 'Reset error handler (not needed only to remind you not just to ignore all errors!
  Do While TypeOf PreviousFormControl Is SubForm ' Loop till control is not subform
      Set PreviousFormControl = PreviousFormControl.Form.ActiveControl ' if subform, previous control of it is its current ActiveControl
  Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Toggle1_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
'Add a 1 to the currently selected control
  PreviousFormControl.Text = PreviousFormControl.Text & "1" ' concat "1" to controls text, no need to handle empty text as it can only be an vbNullString(""), even if Null, then Null & "1"  => "" & "1" => "1"
  PreviousFormControl.SetFocus
End Sub
```

> however if someone knows where I might find code for a customisable number pad that writes directly into whatever window is active

Of course you can use any `Virtual Keyboard` running on windows that fit your needs. But then you may have to handle things like bring keyboard to front on wanted position.
[numpad emulator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/numpad-emulator/) was the first open source app I found on quick search, but looks goods on short test. Of course there may be better solutions out there, just search and test.